# Cells.select except for one field

Tags: vba, excel

In the program I am working on, the previous developer resets elements in a sheet using: `Cells.Select`

The issue is that I've been asked to make some elements clickable with MsgBoxes in these sheets. So what happens is, whenever the sheet is reset using the old developers code, it opens a bunch of message boxes.

Is there a way to use Cells.Select and select everything except the cell D7 for instance? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me :). You should avoid using [.Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). Can you share more details so that we can give you more accurate suggestions.

Comment: check this dude  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154434/how-do-you-get-excel-to-refresh-data-on-sheet-from-within-vba