# VBA formula won't calculate

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and trying to put a formula in that is essentially just a sum function.

It's basically: =sum(A1:A5)

And it works - except it doesn't. When I click on it, it shows that it's working (i.e. it highlights the sum range as if it's calculating), but nothing sums up when I start entering numbers?
I've put this into the code but it still doesn't work: Application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

I've searched the site and google for a solution and it seems other people have had a similar problem but I can't find/understand the solution.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you're having a problem with code then it's best to include it in your post.

Comment: I’m out at the minute but the code that it gets stuck on is: activecell.offset(6,1).formula = “=sum(“ & range(activecell.offset(0,1).address(false, false), activecell.offset(5,1).address(false,false)) & “)”                    The code works as it puts the correct formula in the correct cell, and it even shows that it’s working via the highlighte cells once I go into the formula but it doesn’t actually calculate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/154439/10645228

So you're close - switch it off and on again!

Comment: I’ll give this a go soon, thank you